# How to extract 105 variables for calculation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, batch-processing

I have 7 dataframes of experiments which are each subdivided into 15 repetition (or iteration). I am now interested in all **105** variable `x` for calculation later on in the analysis.

Imagine you have the following dataframes with randomized numbers and, for the sake of simplicity, pretend that all dataframes contain different numbers:

```
set.seed(2)

a <- runif(100, -1.5, 1.5)
b <- pnorm(rnorm(100))
c <- rnorm(100)
d <- rnorm(100)
e <- dnorm(rnorm(100))
iteration <- sort(sample(1:7, 100, replace=T), decreasing=F)
x <- f <- sample(1:1000, 100, replace=T)

df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,iteration,x)
df2 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,iteration,x)
df3 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,iteration,x)
df4 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,iteration,x)
df5 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,iteration,x)
df6 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,iteration,x)
df7 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,iteration,x)
```

How can I break down all 105 variable `x` combination (`df1$x of iteration 1`, `df1$x of iteration 2`, ..., `df7$x of iteration 7`) so that I can calculate the following example nonsense equation for all 105 variable combination?

```
mean(df1$x of iteration 1) - sd(df1$x of iteration 1)
mean(df1$x of iteration 2) - sd(df1$x of iteration 2)
...
mean(df7$x of iteration 7) - sd(df7$x of iteration 7)
```

I have the following command in order to "extract" variable `df1$x of iteration 1` but this would involve 208 more lines to come for the remaining variables:

```
df_1 <- df1[which(df1$iteration=='1'),]
df_1_final <- df_1[grepl("1", df_1$iteration), c(6, 7)]
```

Does this make sense? Is there not a better way to do that in *Gnu R*?

Comment: Try `d1 <- expand.grid(id=paste0('df', 1:7), iteration=1:15);sapply(seq_len(nrow(d1)), function(i) {x1 <- subset(get(as.character(d1[i,1])), iteration==d1[i,2], select=x); mean(x1[,1])- sd(x1[,1])})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a nonsense equation function and then utilize it in `tapply()` with, `iteration` as the INDEX argument, for each df. So for df1: `tapply(df1$x, INDEX = df1$iteration, nonsenseFunction)`, which will return a list/array with all computations for each group(iteration) of df1.

Comment: Thank you very much, small_data88. This solution does function but has to be applied 7 times and its output is not as clear structured as the output of the `bindrows` solution.

Comment: @TilHund Right on and yes the output structure can get kind of messy with `tapply`. I was just trying to show another way to do this, without having to install and learn `dplyr`.

Comment: Fixed with `sort(result,decreasing=F)`.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear that this solution worked out for you.

Answer (score 3):

A possibility using `dplyr`.  Probably easier to work with your `data.frames` in a list (from comments by @akrun)

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(mget(paste0('df', 1:7))) %>%  # put your data.frames in a list -> data.frame
  mutate(group=rep(1:7, each=100)) %>%  # add a grouping column
  group_by(group, iteration) %>%        # group
  summarise(mean(x) - sd(x))            # do your stuff
```

or in `data.table`

```
rbindlist(mget(paste0('df', 1:7)))[,mean(x)-sd(x) ,.(gr=rep(1:7,each=100),iteration)]
```

Comment: Or using `data.table` `rbindlist(mget(paste0('df', 1:7)))[,mean(x)-sd(x) ,.(gr=rep(1:7,each=100),iteration)]`

Comment: It's your idea, I just deleted mine as it was more verbose

Comment: Using 2 revs' and nongkrongs `bindrows` solution with my original data here, I get In `Error: wrong result size (1896), expected 28440 or 1. rbind_all(x) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character`. What did I do wrong?